# Add a suffix to a matched regular expression

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression

I got some lines containing numbers in the first field:

```
46066.874.89
48569.123.56
56489.256.88
654.12.32
84689.25.69
```

What I would like to do now is add `00` at the end of `654` in the fourth line and every other occurrence of three numbers in the file before the first `.`. How would I go about it? I tried using

```
sed 's/^[0-9][0-9][0-9]./&00/'
```

but the output I get is

```
4606006.874.89
4856009.123.56
5648009.256.88
654.0012.32
8468009.25.69
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
$ sed -E 's/^([0-9][0-9][0-9])\./\100./' file 
46066.874.89
48569.123.56
56489.256.88
65400.12.32
84689.25.69
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys, works as intended. Just a quick follow-up question: How would i need to modify the code, if i wanted to match a pattern at the end of a line? Assuming the same numbers are not at the beginning, but the very end. How would i add 00 to 32 in  `654.12.32` ? I feel like I am pretty close again, but cannot take the final step to the correct answer `sed -E 's/\.([0-9][0-9])$/\100./' file`

Comment: @Johnny `sed -E 's/(\.[0-9][0-9])$/\100/' file` should do it.

Comment: @terdon Sadly it doesn't. I get exactly the same output as my input and i absolutely don't understand why. The `(\.[0-9][0-9])$` part matches the last two numbers, but the substitution does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Johnny you probably have spaces after the last number. Try this instead: `sed -E 's/(\.[0-9][0-9]) *$/\100/'  file. If that doesn't work, either ask a new question or come into [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat), the site's main chat room and give me a ping. We shouldn't do this in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sed` command inserts two zeros after three digits and another character at the start of every line.  The `.` matches "any character".  Even if you had escaped the dot as `\.` to match an actual dot, you would have inserted the two zeros *after* the dot.

A slight tweak would make it work:

```
$ sed 's/^\([0-9]\{3\}\)\./\100./' file
46066.874.89
48569.123.56
56489.256.88
65400.12.32
84689.25.69
```

or, if your `sed` has support for extended regular expressions (most have nowadays):

```
$ sed -E 's/^([0-9]{3})\./\100./' file
46066.874.89
48569.123.56
56489.256.88
65400.12.32
84689.25.69
```

---

Using `awk` and making it a bit more generic:

```
$ awk -F . 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } length($1) < 5 { $1 = sprintf("%s%.*d", $1, 5 - length($1), 0) }; 1' file
46066.874.89
48569.123.56
56489.256.88
65400.12.32
84689.25.69
```

This `awk` command will, for each entry in the first dot-delimited column that is less than five characters long, fill out the string with the necessary number of zeroes so that the total length of the string becomes five characters.

This is done with by formatting the integer `0` as a zero filled string to the missing length.  This is then concatenated with the existing data in the field.

This would work for any short string in the first field (not just the ones containing three characters).

Filling out with zeros at the start of the string is easier (but not what was asked for, granted):

```
$ awk -F . 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { $1 = sprintf("%.5d", $1) }; 1' file
46066.874.89
48569.123.56
56489.256.88
00654.12.32
84689.25.69
```

We're just using the fact that the first field contains an integer and format it with `sprintf()` as a zero-filled integer of the correct width.

In both commands, the `1` at the end invokes the default action, which is to print the current line (it could be replaced by `{ print }` or `{ print $0 }`).