# Adding a suffix to a matched regular expression does not work

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression

This is the list of numbers i have:

```
46066.874.89
48569.123.56
56489.256.88
654.12.32
84689.25.69
```

My goal is to add two zeroes at the end of `654.12.32`. But for some reason neither

```
sed -E 's/(\.[0-9][0-9])$/\100/' file
```

nor

```
sed -E 's/(\.[0-9][0-9]) *$/\100/' file
```

work. I get the exact same output as the input. Anyone got an idea what might be going on here?

This is basically a follow-up to my other question from yesterday ([Add a suffix to a matched regular expression](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571366/add-a-suffix-to-a-matched-regular-expression)), but it kinda went off-topic, hence the new question.

Edit:
When i use `od -cb file`, this is the output i get:

```
0000000   4   6   0   6   6   .   8   7   4   .   8   9  \r  \n   4   8
        064 066 060 066 066 056 070 067 064 056 070 071 015 012 064 070
0000020   5   6   9   .   1   2   3   .   5   6  \r  \n   5   6   4   8
        065 066 071 056 061 062 063 056 065 066 015 012 065 066 064 070
0000040   9   .   2   5   6   .   8   8  \r  \n   6   5   4   .   1   2
        071 056 062 065 066 056 070 070 015 012 066 065 064 056 061 062
0000060   .   3   2  \r  \n   8   4   6   8   9   .   2   5   .   6   9
        056 063 062 015 012 070 064 066 070 071 056 062 065 056 066 071
0000100  \r  \n
        015 012
0000102
```

I have no idea how to interpret this though. In case carriage return is activated, how could you go about solving the problem then?

Comment: Suggestion: apply `dos2unix`to the file to convert the line endings (remove the carriage returns `\n`).

Comment: The CR seems to be the problem indeed, after removing them, it works. Thank you very much guys! But i am still curious: Why does it prevent the code from working? And is there any way to make it still work without removing the CR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because you're trying to match `[0-9]` at the end of a line but your input doesn't HAVE `[0-9]` at the end of any line, every line ends with `[0-9]\r`. You can make the regexp match by using `/...[0-9]\r$/` instead of `...[0-9]$/` in your regexp. See [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it?noredirect=1#comment97778025_45772525](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it?noredirect=1#comment97778025_45772525) for more info on DOS line endings.

Here's how to handle just UNIX line endings, just DOS line endings, and both:

```
$ printf '654.12.32\n' | cat -v
654.12.32

$ printf '654.12.32\r\n' | cat -v
654.12.32^M

$ printf '654.12.32\n' | sed -E 's/\.([0-9][0-9])$/\100/' | cat -v
654.123200

$ printf '654.12.32\r\n' | sed -E 's/\.([0-9][0-9])$/\100/' | cat -v
654.12.32^M

$ printf '654.12.32\r\n' | sed -E 's/\.([0-9][0-9])\r$/\100/' | cat -v
654.123200

$ printf '654.12.32\r\n' | sed -E 's/\.([0-9][0-9])(\r?)$/\100\2/' | cat -v
654.123200^M

$ printf '654.12.32\n' | sed -E 's/\.([0-9][0-9])(\r?)$/\100\2/' | cat -v
654.123200
```

Comment: I see it now. Carriage-Return and Line Feed are considered part of the line and need to be part of the regular expression as well, silly of me not to think about it. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on context. In Windows `\r\n` is the newline and so is not part of the line that you see within any tool that reads 1 newline-separated string at a time. In UNIX the same is true for just `\n`. So in UNIX tools, by default the `\r` is part of the string (line) that the tool is operating on just like any other character while in DOS it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this may work:

```
sed -E 's/^(.{3}\..{2}\..{2})$/\100/' file
```

Output:

```
46066.874.89
48569.123.56
56489.256.88
654.12.3200
84689.25.69
```

---

Your regex doesn't work because it maches

```
46066.874.89
48569.123.56
56489.256.88
654.12.32
84689.25.69
```

so the output is:

```
46066.874.8900
48569.123.5600
56489.256.8800
654.12.3200
84689.25.6900
```

Comment: This is actually the better solution to my question from yesterday, thanks for posting it! I didn't even really check the results of the codes yesterday, because the problem with the CR's took all my attention.